# How to run only controller tests in MiniTest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-line, minitest

What is the rake command for running only controller tests in minitest?
`rake test:controller` doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try making it plural. This is the typical command:

```
rake test:controllers
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#rake-tasks-for-running-your-tests

Section 6 covers the rake commands for testing.

Comment: That is a very useful portion of the testing page.

Answer (score 6):

Has to be plural `rake test:controllers` as you're running all of them.

Please take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#rake-tasks-for-running-your-tests for more rake commands.

If you want to run a specific file, then use the `TEST` argument:

`rake test TEST=test/controllers/application_controller_test.rb`

Answer (score 1):

As an update:

`rails test path/to/test/file.rb` has become my go-to solution.
`rails test path/to/test/file.rb:123` lets you pick the test via line number as well.